# How to check if a user's new email has been verified

Tags: craft3, users, emails, frontend

#### Background

When the user setting `Verify email addresses?` is enabled, and the user's email is reset by a non-admin the address requires verification before being used  [as explained here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2693#issuecomment-379519212). This does not seem to show any sort of confirmation anywhere that the email reset has been made until the user verifies it. The account seems to stay live also, so checking pending users does not help.

#### Question

Is there an attribute or function I can call to find out if the email is verified?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you are looking for, but one way to approach the problem:

You are able to set the STMP, IMAP credentials for the email service that Craft uses. Maybe use a service that has read receipts and use that to see if the new user has checked the confirmation email?